# Woocommerce script not loading

Tags: woocommerce

Woocommerce should load 5 additional script files onto a site, however I'm unable to find out why one in particular will not load.

The files that should load are:

```
add-to-cart.min.js
jquery.blockUI.min.js
woocommerce.min.js
jquery.cookie.min.js
cart-fragments.min.js
```

However, `add-to-cart.min.js` does not load. I have attempted to re-install Woocommerce, and also disable my theme and go back to the default TwentyTwenty theme. I've also disabled all plugins apart from WC. No luck with any of these.

Has anybody come across this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this comes up fro anyone else, it appears the `add-to-cart.min.js` only loads if 'Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives' is enabled in the WC settings.